# Important steps and strategies for solving puzzles

Tags: strategy

What are the necessary steps for solving any puzzle?

Comment: Is this too broad? There are many kinds of puzzles, each require different methods. @OP What are you asking for?

Comment: I just asked main strategy for solving any puzzle

Comment: You seem to be looking for something that does not exist, quite frankly. If there was a universal strategy that could solve *literally any puzzle*, this site would crumble overnight because every single question would be answerable with that exact strategy.

Comment: There is no main strategy, because there is no main puzzle. There are many puzzles. Many, *many* puzzles. You just gotta adapt. Some tags in Puzzling help you to enter the right mindset and know what to look for, so you can rely on them. People are different, and so each puzzle is bound to have its own unique flavour and/or style, hence why your question is rather broad, as it is focused on *any* puzzle. So I suggest that the best way to become a good puzzler, is to solve some; create some; and repeat :)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what kind of puzzle it is. Sometimes you just have to consider all the facts and make a deduction. The facts will be given to you and you just have to connect them in the right way.

Then there are open-ended puzzles, like those puzzles about graph theory(you've probably seen them). In these puzzles what you have to do is just to investigate. You usually will not be able to tackle the big problem all at once, so try to simplify the question a little bit and work on that version of the question instead. If you can not find a way to simplify it, just play with the puzzle. Do anything you like, as long as it is about the puzzle at your hands. It will not always lead to a solution but you will have more information about the puzzle, making it easier for you to reach to an answer.

But, at the end of the day, it is up to you to solve a puzzle. The "step"s I provided are very broad. I can tell you this though: Be stubborn. There were a lot of puzzles where I thought it was impossible for someone like me to find a solution. Even though some of them took days to solve, I did solve them.

I am no expert though. I might be giving wrong advice here. I am just sharing what I learned through my own experiences and what worked for me.

Comment: $(+1)$ For the first sentence ;)